# fragments in tabview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

i am creating a tab view in that when a button is clicked it must move to another screen when i try to implement it using the above code it is changing to another screen but the button is still visible with next screen and i want next screen should cover entire screen

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment  {
LinearLayout mLayout;
/** (non-Javadoc)
* @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,      android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
 */
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

if (container == null) {


    return null;
}

LinearLayout theLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout, container, false);

        // Register for the Button.OnClick event

        Button b = (Button)theLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                 Fragment mFragment = new third_fragment_view();
                 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                 ft.replace(R.id.container, mFragment);
                 ft.addToBackStack(null);
                 ft.commit();   


            }

        });

return theLayout;

}
} 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#00bfff"
android:id="@+id/container1" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Ui to cover the entire Screen dn't use Fragments.Use Intents

```
 b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent=new Intent();
       intent.setClass(thisactivity.class,targetactivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       }
    });
```

Comment: but i want to open that activity in the same tab if i use as you said then it will open in it in a new window not under my tab

Comment: Ok.On Cliking the Button What Should be displayed.according to ur Requirement

Comment: u need to display an emptyScreen with out the button.is it correcet?that is ur requirement r not?

Comment: no my requirement is  when i click that button a xml layout should displayed in the entire screen(not the previous layout) but in the same tab

Comment: and the blue screen in the image is a different layout